# Why Cant My Nuxt Middleware Get The Updated Store State Even After Mutations?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Here is my code, i am using vuex-persisted-state as a plugin and state persists after page reload , However when i console my state in the middleware it always returns false :

store code:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'


const createStore = () => {

  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: () => ({
      truthy: false,

    }),

    mutations: {
      changeState(state, truthy) {
        state.truthy = truthy
      }
    },

  })
}
export default createStore
```

My page code

```
    <template>
      <button @click="change">Change</button>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      export default {
        middleware: 'authenticated',
        methods: {
          change() {
            this.$store.commit('changeState', true)
          }
        }
      }
    
    </script>
```

My Plugin Code

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
export default ({ store }) => {
  createPersistedState({})(store)
}
```

Middleware Code

```
export default function ({ store, redirect,req }) {
    console.log(store.state)
  }
```

Comment: Just a quick testing advise: add `console.log(truthy)` to your `changeState` mutation to check, if it´s even get called.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with `vuex-persisted-state` only works client side and middleware getting executed server side, depending on the projects ssr setup.